# Optimizing for random reads

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

First of all, I am using MongoDB 3.0 with the new WiredTiger storage engine. Also using snappy for compression.

The use case I am trying to understand and optimize for from a technical point of view is the following;

I have a fairly large collection, with about 500 million documents that takes about 180 GB including indexes.

Example document:

```
{
  _id: 123234,
  type: "Car",
  color: "Blue",
  description: "bla bla" 
}
```

Queries consist of finding documents with a specific field value. Like so;

```
thing.find( { type: "Car" } )
```

In this example the `type` field should obviously be indexed. So far so good. However the access pattern for this data will be completely random. At a given time I have no idea what range of documents will be accessed. I only know that they will be queried on indexed fields, returning at the most 100000 documents at a time.

What this means in my mind is that the caching in MongoDB/WiredTiger is pretty much useless. The only thing that needs to fit in the cache are the indexes. An estimation of the working set is hard if not impossible?

What I am looking for is mostly tips on what kinds of indexes to use and how to configure MongoDB for this kind of use case. Would other databases work better?

Currently I find MongoDB to work quite well on somewhat limited hardware (16 GB RAM, non SSD disc). Queries return in decent time and obviously instantly if the result set is already in the cache. But as already stated this will most likely not be the typical case. It is not critical that the queries are lightning fast, more so that they are dependable and that the database will run in a stable manner.

**EDIT:**

Guess I left out some important things. The database will be mostly for archival purposes. As such, data arrives from another source in bulk, say once a day. Updates will be very rare.

The example I used was a bit contrived but in essence that is what queries look like. When I mentioned multiple indexes I meant the `type` and `color` fields in that example. So documents will be queried on using these fields. As it is now, we only care about returning all documents that have a specific `type`, `color` etc. Naturally, the plan we have is to only query on fields that we have an index for. So ad-hoc queries are off the table.

Right now the index sizes are quite manageable. For the 500 million documents each of these indexes are about 2.5GB and fit easily in RAM.

Regarding average data size of an operation, I can only speculate at this point. As far as I know, typical operations return about 20k documents, with an average object size in the range of 1200 bytes. This is the stat reported by `db.stats()` so I guess it is for the compressed data on disc, and not how much it actually takes once in RAM.

Hope this bit of extra info helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if you have a consistent rate of reads that are uniformly at random over `type` (which is what I'm taking

> I have no idea what range of documents will be accessed

to mean), then you will see stable performance from the database. It will be doing some stable proportion of reads from cache, just by good luck, and another stable proportion by reading from disk, especially if the number and size of documents are about the same between different `type` values. I don't think there's a special index or anything to help you besides just better hardware. Indexes should remain in RAM because they'll constantly be being used.

I suppose more information would help, as you mention only one simple query on `type` but then talk about having multiple indexes to worry about keeping in RAM. How much data does the average operation return? Do you ever care to return a subset of docs of certain `type` or only all of them? What do inserts and updates to this collection look like?

Also, if the documents being read are truly completely random over the dataset, then the working set is all of the data.